# C# EF Call the Many-to-Many relationship class to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

Good day,

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship with 3 tables. And the many-to-many table will be called to another table using ASP.NET Core Entity Framework Core.

Here's the scenario: Suppose I'm creating a customer appointment for a barber shop service.

I have 3 tables. `Calendar`, `HairCutOffer` and `CalendarHairCutOffer` (which is the many-to-many table.

Calendar.cs

```
public class Calendar {
    [Key] public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    public string CalendarName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidityFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidityTo { get; set; }
}
```

HairCutOffer.cs

```
public class HairCutOffer {
    [Key] public int HairCutOfferId { get; set; }
    public string HaitCutName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

CalendarHairCutOffer.cs

```
public class CalendarHairCutOffer { 
    public Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
    public HairCutOffer HairCutOffer { get; set; }

    public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    public int HairCutOfferId { get; set; }
}
```

Please confirm if I'm doing it correctly when it comes to many-to-many relationship.

My next problem is, I have another table which is the `CustomerAppointment` that can select a Calendar and HairCutOffer within that Calendar.

```
public class CustomerAppointment {
    public int CustomerAppointmentId { get; set; }
    // how to call the calendarhaircutoffer here?
}
```

How can I implement my many-to-many table which is `CalendarHairCutOffer` to my `CustomerAppointment`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In `CustomerAppointment` do you need many to many relationship of `CalendarHairCutOffer` (i.e. `collection of CalendarHairCutOffer`  like `List<CalendarHairCutOffer>`). Based on your defined schema and question, it seems that you each `CustomerAppointment ` is going to have only one `CalendarHairCutOffer`. If that is correct then define it should be defined as `public int CalendarHairCutOfferId {get; set; }`

Comment: Yes sir in one `CustomerAppointment` he/she can do one calendar date and time haircut service. Like a customer book a schedule in a given calendar date and its service. But sir, I don't have `CalendarHairCutOfferId` in my `CalendarHairCutOffer` class

Comment: Not for the solution of your question, but you can define `CalendarHairCutOfferId` as clustered primary key on `CalendarHairCutOffer` which would benefit in performance scenarios too and to attain your requirement.

Comment: Oh I understand sir. But does my schema's okay sir? I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly in my many-to-may

Comment: Looks good except defining `CalendarHairCutOfferId`. Also, attach the `ForeignKey` on foreign keys. Also, if you want to have navigation from `Calendar` to `CalendarHairCutOffer` then you can add the `List<CalendarHairCutOffer>` in `Calendar ` class (same applies to `HairCutOffer`).

Comment: Because what's on my mind. `Calendar` has multiple `HairCutOffer` has multiple `Calendar`. Suppose I have multiple `HairCutOffer` like: `male clean cut, female clean cut, male trim, female trim`  and let's say I have a `Calendar` with a name of `MaleHairCutCalendar` inside of the calendar, it includes multiple `HairCutOffer` for only man. while my calendar `FemaleMaleHairCutCalendar` consists only `HairCutOffer` for female. Does my schema applies that?

Comment: Offer for female or mail should be derived by offer type (or other property) instead of creating different tables.

Comment: But is it okay to just create `CalendarHairCutOffer` table to store `Calendar` and `HairCutOffer` instead?

Comment: Do you really need many to many here? The way I see it is, `HairCutOffer` have a property of `ValidityFrom` and `ValidityTo`. After all HairCutOffer is a 'coupon' right? Then from there `CustomerAppointment` can have 0 or 1 `HairCutOffer`

Comment: The `Calendar` has the `ValidityFrom` and `ValidityTo` not the `HairCutOffer` @penleychan

Comment: @jsonGPPD, Yes i know, i was just saying do you really need that `Calendar` entity, what purpose does it serve?

Comment: It's for `Calendar` validity only.